# Obtener JAR de cliente EJB

Tags: java

[image: Archivo .war]Tengo una aplicacion Web que tiene un modulo EJB y quiero obtener el JAR del cliente EJB. Pero me aparece un error.[image: Error]

¿Alguien me podría ayudar y decirme cómo abrir el EAR y extraer el archivo JAR que necesito.

Comment: Con cualquier compresor de ficheros puedes abrirlos. Winzip, winrar, 7z...

Answer (score 0):

El error está diciendo claramente que  `RegistrationRequestedPortImpl` y `RegistrationPortImpl` tienen el mismo `URL pattern`.

No entiendo bien si la pregunta es sobre cómo poder extraer un `JAR` de un `EAR` **literalmente** o si quiere es llamarlo a partir de otro módulo.

En todo caso, si es la primera, para qué quiere tener acceso a archivos `.class` ?  De ser así, @Dani tiene razón, cualquier compresor de archivos...

Si es la segunda, un EJB se puede injectar de la siguiente forma, en cualquier `bean`:

```
@EJB
private NombreEJB nombreRef;
```

O manualmente utilizando un [lookup](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15505/access.htm#i1020064):

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
      NombreEJB nomEJB = (NombreEJB) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/NombreEJB");
```